# Not able to scrape content from myntra

Tags: php, curl

Was trying to **scrape** content from myntra with below given code, the same code is working fine for snapdeal, anyone can help me out where am i stucking ??

```
$url = 'www.myntra.com/tshirts/roadster/roadster-men-black-striped-polo-collar-t-shirt/1353945/buy?src=search&uq=false&q=men-tshirts&p=1';
         $request_headers = '[
                "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml, text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5",
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
                "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",
            ]';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100508 SeaMonkey/2.0.4');
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

        $cl  = curl_exec($ch);
        //print_r($cl);
        if($cl === false){

             echo 'Curl error: '.curl_errno($ch). '-' . curl_error($ch);

        }else{
             $dom = new DOMDocument();

             $dom->loadHTML($cl);

             $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

             $pName = $xpath->query('//h1[@class="pdp-title"]/text()'); //pdp-title  pdp-e-i-head

             $pro   = $pName->item(0)->nodeValue;

             echo $pro;
             //var_dump($pName);
        }
```

while doing curl it is giving the error "Curl error: 47-Maximum (20) redirects followed",
as i am new to this basically not getting what to do next...

while removing if else condition it showing domnodeobject: value ommited,

Not gettting any clue , what's the actual cause of this problem.

i run curl on command prompt it was displaying the page correctly, but by hitting through browser it continuously giving error: "Curl error: 47-Maximum (20) redirects followed"..

Thanks in advance, waiting for suggestions....

Comment: This site is JS based. You can't scrape javascript based sites with curl.

Comment: what are the other way i can try with ?

Comment: One option is to use phantomjs for an example to render the JS or try find from where the js is loading the content and parse the json.

Comment: any best document can u suggest for phantomjs
?

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1. Render the JS content on the webpage. You can use PhantomJS to render. Check this tutorial http://shout.setfive.com/2015/03/30/7817/
2. Parse directly the json file:

   http://www.myntra.com/web/style/similar/Roadster-Men%20Black%20Striped%20Polo%20Collar%20T-shirt/1353945

Answer (score -1):

Scraping Myntra can be easily done using nodejs. You can use cheerio to load and inject jquery and access all the elements you want and scrape them, you can also use fast-csv or some other npm library to export the data in your desired format. This approach is faster than phantom.js

Here is a great article on scotch.io to get you started

https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js